# Characterisation of functions with an essential singularity

Tags: complex-analysis, singularity, weierstrass-approximation

My professor claimed the following result:

> If a function has an essential singularity at $z_0$
>
> Then it can be approximated by $e^{1/z_0}$, or in general, $e^{f(z)}$, where $f(z)$ has a pole at $z_0$.

The only example of functions with an essential singularity that I know is $e^{1/z_0}$

I thought about applying Stone–Weierstrass Theorem, that exponentials and polynomials are dense in the space of continuous functions, but I am not sure how to rigorously prove the above claim.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: $e^{1/z_0}$ is a single function, what exactly does “approximate by $e^{1/z_0}$” mean?

Comment: i.e. the asymptotic behavior of this function is similar to $e^{f(z)}$, where $f(z)$ has a pole at $z_0$

Comment: Martin R accidently used the wrong word. $e^{1/z_0}$ is a single *value*, not a function at all. $z$ is the variable, $z_0$ is a constant. Your professor surely offered $e^{1/(z-z_0)}$ as a sample function. But this function is not going to approximate all functions with essential singularities. For example, it does not approximate $-e^{1/(z-z_0)}$. What is true is that *behavior* of this function about the singularity is indicative of how all isolated essential singularities behave. Also, every non polynomial analytic function has an essential singularity on the Riemann sphere.